# Strange CLR results when maniupating strings in CLR

Tags: sql-server-2008, clr, arrays

This is a little difficult to describe but I'll give it a try.

I have some CLR code that I am calling from a UDF in SQL Server 2008.  The Master Database and the Database containing the CLR code and UDFs have different collations.

Inside the CLR code I am manipulating varchar strings, e.g., converting to byte[] array and back again.

The thing is, when converting to byte[] array abd back again, it seems to be using the collation of the Master database, even though, as I said, the CLR code and the UDFs are entirely in the application database and no reference is ever made to the Master database.

Is there a way to force the CLR code to use the collation of the database it is part of, rather than the Master database?

I hope this is clear.

Thanks.

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd show the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

A System.String in .Net is not SQL collation aware - all strings are stored in Unicode, so the problem you're experiencing is almost certainly going to be the result of the byte[] manipulation.